# mysql select dynamic row values as column names as follow

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my mysql query

```
SELECT research_id,
@availability:=if(product_id=4,value,'') AS availability,
@cooler:=if(product_id=5,value,'') AS Cooler,
@coolerLocation:=if(product_id=9,value,'') AS CoolerLocation
FROM research_product_details rpd
LEFT JOIN products p
ON rpd.product_id = p.id
WHERE product_id = 4 OR product_id = 5 OR product_id = 9
ORDER BY research_id ASC, product_id ASC
```

and i got this result

[image]

And this is not the result what i want, i want it like this,

[image]

Comment: Used group by clause i.e `GROUP BY Research_id`

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you have a look at this query?

Comment: Can you show the source data and the ddl of both tables.

Comment: i try that, it doesn't work. i got only first column data when group it by research_id

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUP BY` with `MAX()` to flatten the table

```
SELECT research_id,
    MAX(if(product_id=4,value, NULL)) AS availability,
    MAX(if(product_id=5,value, NULL)) AS Cooler,
    MAX(if(product_id=9,value, NULL)) AS CoolerLocation
FROM research_product_details rpd
LEFT JOIN products p
ON rpd.product_id = p.id
WHERE product_id = 4 OR product_id = 5 OR product_id = 9
GROUP BY research_id 
ORDER BY research_id ASC, product_id ASC
```

Comment: Try now. You were mixing types.